# How to replicate a conda environment?

Tags: python, windows, conda

I have successfully installed some python code on a Win10 machine using Anaconda and conda environments and would like to install exactly the same environment on another computer, also Win10.

[This page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments)  indicates that you can save a file that contains the environment info on computer 1, then recall it on computer 2, using:

1. computer 1: `conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt`
2. copy the file from the working directory of computer 1 to the working directory of computer 2
3. computer 2: `conda create --name myenv --file spec-file.txt`

Step 1 works fine for me but step 3 fails with a `ResolvePackageNotFound` error, listing basically all the packages that are in the text file.

Am I missing something?
Is there a way to semi-automatically install the packages from that text file instead?

###### Edit: summary from the answers and comments (thank you!):

- if `conda install` was used to install packages in computer 1, then what is written above is the best way to do an exact replication.
- if `pip install` was used instead for packages installation (as was the case for me), the chosen solution below is the most appropriate one (`conda env export` and `conda env create`)

Comment: Could you add more details as to exactly what package failed to be resolved? The `--explicit` option is the correct approach for *exact* replication (identical package builds), not `conda env export`, which is a slightly looser replication, but also captures PyPI packages. How old is the environment? Possible it includes packages that were removed or moved to a different channel (e.g., Anaconda moved packages from `defaults` to `free` some years back).

Comment: Thanks for the comment; 1. It looks like all the packages that are in the environment fail. There's about 100 of them. Nothing gets actually installed with the `conda create` instruction. I should specify that after creating the environment, on Computer 1, I only used `conda install` for spyder, the other modules are installed with `pip install`. 2. I did the install on computer 1 about 1.5 year ago, so not that old.

Comment: I think the main problem I have is that one of the packages used (`isosplit5`) relies on visual studio to be compiled or something (I really don't know how it works, but the error messages I got point to that). I was hoping that by doing an exact replication of all the modules, it would bypass this, but apparently not. I should probably open another Question for this.

Comment: In that case (i.e., using Pip), `conda list --explicit` won't work; `conda env export` is your only option.

Comment: OK that's good to know! I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using export --

Computer 1 - `conda env export > spec-file.yml`

Computer 2 - `conda env create -f spec-file.yml`

Comment: That worked much better, thanks! It actually started installing modules. Unfortunately it didn't fully work and generated the same errors that I got when trying to install these modules one by one on 'computer 2' - I was hoping that replicating the conda environment would bypass these errors but apparently not. I'll accept your answer though as it solved the question.

Comment: is the conda config the same on both hosts? try comparing the output of `conda config --show`

Comment: Good point, they are slightly different: computer 2 has conda version 23.5.2 and has a few more available options, also its default python is 3.11, computer 1 has conda version  4.13.0 (wow, that seems like a huge difference) and default python 3.9. The only other visible difference apart from missing options is `experimental_solver`: `classic` for computer 1, `[]` (empty) for computer 2. I'm not sure if the default python is important since I force the use of the same python when creating my environment...

Comment: The **base** Python would make no difference; the Conda version...maybe. v4.13 isn't old, rather Conda switched to date versioning (YY.M.D). Most likely difference is channels and channel configuration: the `conda env export` command does not capture channel-of-origin for each package, but rather simply puts the user's current channel configuration into the `channel:` section of the YAML. That could be inconsistent with where the packages came from if `conda install -c` was used. Additionally, the `conda env create` will append the current user channels, possibly different.

Comment: @merv thank you, that makes sense. In this case I only use `conda` to create the environment, after that I use `pip install` for all the modules. So any differences in channels should not matter, right?

Comment: does not work for me