Porting conda environments from intel to M2?/
I've been unknowingly using the intel version of anaconda to manage my python environments on my M2 mac mini, but I am now considering making the switch to the ARM64 version.
How would you recommend I go about doing so? I would very much like to avoid having to reinstall all the packages in my various environments from scratch. Thank you!

You can try this for each of your environments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76867905/189418


I would very much like to avoid having to reinstall all the packages in my various environments from scratch.

You will need to reinstall all packages, as you will need to install an arm64 version of python and then you need the compatible versions of packages.
You can make the process a bit easier, if you create a yml file from your environment using
conda env export --from-history -n <your env name> > env.yml

and after uninstalling anaconda and installing the new version (do not try to have both versions alongside, only creates headaches), you can create the environment again from this file:
conda env create -f env.yml

Note that you might still run into trouble in cases where packages are not available for arm64 when they are for x64
